# Create a variable capturing the most frequent occurence by group

Tags: r, count, frequency, data-manipulation, data-management

Define:

```
df1 <-data.frame(
id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),
v1=as.character(c("a","b","b",rep("c",3)))
)
```

s.t.

```
> df1
  id v1
1  1  a
2  1  b
3  1  b
4  2  c
5  2  c
6  2  c
```

I want to create a third variable `freq` that contains the most frequent observation in `v1` by `id` s.t.

```
> df2
  id v1 freq
1  1  a    b
2  1  b    b
3  1  b    b
4  2  c    c
5  2  c    c
6  2  c    c
```

Comment: how are ties supposed to be handled within id group?

Comment: @Chase In my case I am sure there are no ties.

Comment: Good question about ties, I'll make a note about how my solution handles that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `ddply` and a custom function to pick out the most frequent value:

```
myFun <- function(x){
    tbl <- table(x$v1)
    x$freq <- rep(names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)],nrow(x))
    x
}

ddply(df1,.(id),.fun=myFun)
```

Note that `which.max` will return the first occurrence of the maximum value, in the case of ties. See ??which.is.max in the `nnet` package for an option that breaks ties randomly.

Answer (score 3):

Another way consists of using `tidyverse` functions:

- grouping first, using `group_by()`, and counting the occurrence of the second variable using `tally()`
- arranging by the number of occurrences with `arrange()`
- summarizing and picking out the first row with `summarize()` and `first()`

Therefore:

```
df1 %>%
group_by(id, v1) %>%
tally() %>%
arrange(id, desc(n)) %>%
summarize(freq = first(v1))
```

This will give you just the mapping (which I find cleaner):

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     id   freq
  <dbl> <fctr>
1     1      b
2     2      c
```

You can then `left_join` your original data frame with that table.

Comment: I like that approach because one can check for and identify ties after `tally()`. That might be possible with @joran's great function too but not so straight forward as here, at least for me

Answer (score 1):

```
mode <- function(x) names(table(x))[ which.max(table(x)) ]
df1$freq <- ave(df1$v1, df1$id, FUN=mode)
> df1
  id v1 freq
1  1  a    b
2  1  b    b
3  1  b    b
4  2  c    c
5  2  c    c
6  2  c    c
```

Comment: I think `df2` is a typo, and when I run this I get `NA`s for `id`=2.

Comment: The typo is gone, but I still don't think this code works. When id=2, max(table(x)) returns 3, but table(x) has only 1 name, so your function mode returns NA.

Comment: It is accidentally giving the correct result, because of an accident of factors. df$id is a factor and the 3rd level is "c". Fixed.