# Least occurring element in vector R

Tags: r

If I have a vector

```
vec = c('a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c')
```

Is there a simple way to find the least occurring element in `vec`? Thanks!

Edit: is there a simple way to do it with characters?

Comment: The answer I gave should not have depended on the vector being numeric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, even if more than one of the elements is tied as the least frequent item:

```
vec = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)

f <- table(vec)
as.numeric(names(f[f == min(f)]))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
table(vec)[which.min(table(vec))]
```

(In all likelihood a duplicate, although I have searched. Found what seemed to be similar on the max side: [Create a variable capturing the most frequent occurence by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513378/create-a-variable-capturing-the-most-frequent-occurence-by-group)  Maybe it sounds familiar to that one 'cuz I posted an answer?)

Comment: I was thinking of comparing elapsed time for this vs. `min(hist(charto8bit(vec))$counts)`  but thought that would be a candidate for thedailywtf's Code SOD :-)